# ADSI not validating correctly?

Tags: powershell, variables, powershell-cmdlet

I have a CSV with 1500+ users there are 30 users per class OU, and then 6 class OU's per Intake OU. What I'm trying to achieve is, `foreach (user in CSV)`, check if OU exists, then check if parent OU exists, create the parent OU only if it doesn't exist, then create the OU, then create the user, or just create the user if the OU exists.

Here is the code I'm using:

```cs
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\AddPupils.csv" 

foreach ($user in $CSV) {
    # Variables
    $GivenName = $user.GivenName
    $SurName = $user.SurName
    $UserName = $user.UserName
    $Class = $user.YearClass
    $Intake = $user.Intake
    $DisplayName = $GivenName+" "+$SurName

    # Create User
    $UserOUParent = "OU=Year "+$iIntake+" Intake,OU=Students,OU=Users,OU=Roding,DC=Zulbag,DC=com"
    $UserOU = "OU=Class "+$Class.Substring(1,1)+",OU=Year "+$iIntake+" Intake,OU=Students,OU=Users,OU=Roding,DC=Zulbag,DC=com"
    $NewUserOUParentCheck = [ADSI]::Exists("LDAP://$UserOUParent")
    $NewUserOUCheck = [ADSI]::Exists("LDAP://$UserOU")

    if ($NewUserOUCheck -eq $false){
        if ($NewUserOUParentCheck -eq $false){
            "Create Parent Ou"
            New-ADOrganizationalUnit `
                -Name ("Year "+$Intake+" Intake") `
                -Path "OU=Students,OU=Users,OU=Roding,DC=Zulbag,DC=Com" `
                -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $False
        }
        "Create OU"
        New-ADOrganizationalUnit `
            -Name ("Class "+$Class.Substring(1,1)) `
            -Path ("OU=Year "+$Intake+" Intake,OU=Students,OU=Users,OU=Roding,DC=Zulbag,DC=Com") `
            -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $False
    }
    "Create User"
    New-ADUser `
        -Name $DisplayName `
        -SurName $SurName `
        -GivenName $GivenName `
        -DisplayName $DisplayName `
        -SamAccountName $UserName `
        -UserPrincipalName ($UserName+"@Zulbag.com") `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Testing123" -AsPlainText -force) `
        -CannotChangePassword $true `
        -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false `
        -PasswordNeverExpires $true `
        -EmailAddress ($UserName+"@Zulbag.com") `
        -Country "GB" `
        -Path ("OU=Class "+$Class.Substring(1,1)+",OU=Year "+$Intake+" Intake,OU=Students,OU=Users,OU=Roding,DC=Zulbag,DC=Com") `
        -ProfilePath ("D:\Shares\User Accounts\Students\Intake Year "+$Intake+"\Class "+$Class.Substring(1,1)+"\Profiles\"+$DisplayName) `
        -Enabled $true

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    # Add To Group  
    $Group = "CN=Redirection "+$Intake.Substring(2,2)+$Class.Substring(1,1)+",OU=Intake "+$Intake+",OU=Security Groups,OU=Roding,DC=Zulbag,DC=Com"
    $GroupOU = "OU=Intake "+$Intake+",OU=Folder Redirection Groups,OU=Security Groups,OU=Roding,DC=Zulbag,DC=Com"
    $NewGroupCheck = [ADSI]::Exists("LDAP://$Group")
    $NewGroupOUCheck = [ADSI]::Exists("LDAP://$GroupOU")

    if ($NewGroupCheck -eq $false) {
        if ($NewGroupOUCheck -eq $false) {
            "Create OU"
            New-ADOrganizationalUnit `
                -Name ("Intake "+$Intake) `
                -Path "OU=Folder Redirection Groups,OU=Security Groups,OU=Roding,DC=Zulbag,DC=Com" `
                -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $False
        }
        "create Group"
        New-ADGroup `
            -Name ("Redirection "+$Intake.Substring(2,2)+$Class.Substring(1,1)) `
            -GroupScope "Global" `
            -Path ("OU=Intake "+$Intake+",OU=Folder Redirection Groups,OU=Security Groups,OU=Roding,DC=Zulbag,DC=Com")
    }
    "Add Member"
    Add-ADGroupMember ("Redirection "+$Intake.Substring(2,2)+$Class.Substring(1,1)) $UserName
}

pause
```

Sample CSV:

```
GivenName,SurName,Class,UserName,Intake
Ali,Grisdale,1B,AGris,2016
Ayomiposi,Olayera,1B,AOlay,2016
```

In tests with `Write-Output`, the `[ADSI]` validates correctly but it appears to be validating it incorrectly here, the error message I keep getting is:

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit : An attempt was made to add an object to the 
directory with a name that is already in use
At C:\Scripts\AddPupils-Afzal.ps1:24 char:13
+             New-ADOrganizationalUnit 
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (OU=Year 2016 In...C=Zulbag,DC=Com:String) [New-ADOrganizationalUnit], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8305,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADOrganizationalUnitdirectory
```

It successfully creates the parent OU, class OU and user, but fails to create the second user, instead validates the OU incorrectly again.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This is backwards. Test if the OU exists first, create it if it's missing, *then* create the new user.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, i failed to mention that I will be doing an import for 1500+ users and there will be 30 users per OU, what im trying to do is create the OU only if it doesn't exist, then create the rest of the users in that OU, it works without putting the cmdlet in the variable

Comment: That doesn't change anything about your approach being backwards. Again, test if the OU exists. Create it if it's missing. Then create the new user(s).

Comment: This isnt going so well for me, im using this: [ADSI]::Exists(“LDAP://OU, but this keep giving me the wrong result, it creates the first parent ou, then ou, then user, then tries to create the same parent ou on the next user (which it shouldnt), any suggestions? Im even using if ($test -eq $false) which was advised on another thread

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your updated code as well as the error message.

Comment: Look, none of us but you are sitting in front of your compüter, so you need to *show* us the code you have. Not some crippled fragment that might look remotely like your actual code. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're experiencing, and update your question with *that* code as well as the full, unaltered error message that code is giving you.

Comment: Sorry, Updated with complete code, and unaltered error

Comment: `$Intake` != `$iIntake`.

Comment: im seeing all the errors, fixed, thanks for your help and suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the script for path errors!